# Application to find duplicate MP3s

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find duplicate songs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4323/how-can-i-find-duplicate-songs)

I'm looking for a program to find duplicate MP3 files.

The program shouldn't use MD5 hashes but it should find similar file names. (Something like Anti-Twin for Windows).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

There is a graphical tool called [fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) that has an option to search for duplicate files based on filename.
If this is what you were looking for you can install it by executing `sudo apt-get install fslint`.